# What is faster for storing and manipulating a grid: 2D array, 1D array or a hash table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance, hashtable

For my **Node.js** application I need to choose the best performing structure to represent a grid.

My requirements/limitations are:

- The grid to store is two-dimensional by nature (x, y) and not very large (100-300 cells)
- Some cells in the grid contain nothing, i.e. the grid will be empty for up to 25%
- I will have to address the grid very often. I'll need to do some heavy
  algorithms to the grid, like *flood-fill*, *A** pathfinding and some more
- This will be a repetitive simulation process of changing the grid and applying the algorithms again
- I aim at hundreds of simulations in a limited time, so every millisecond matters
- I do not care about readability of the code
- Amount of memory used is also a minor concern
- Switch to another programming language is not possible

I've been choosing between three options:

```js
var grid = [height][width];
grid[y][x] = {};
```

```js
var grid = [height * width]; 
grid[y * height + x] = {}; 
var y = ~~(index % height); 
var x = index - height * y;
```

```js
var grid = []; 
var key = x + ',' + y; 
grid[key] = {};
```

The **first one** is the most comfortable as I will manipulate the coordinates a lot, meaning `x` and `y` will be handy all the time. Possible disadvantage - I've read it could be much slower when holding objects in comparison to 1D array.

The **second** is fine and probably very fast. But I will need to convert `index` to `x` and `y` and vice versa which is extra calculations involving modulo for index to coords conversion. Still I see this approach in many good sources.

The **third way** is new to me but I've seen it in some robust code examples and I've read that retrieving an object from hash table can be faster in comparison to 2D array as well.

I do not trust synthetic benchmarks too much so I do not wish to set up a code competition with *almost* empty logic so far. But I'm afraid it will be a very long way back if I pick a wrong way now and then will have to revert.

I've seen similar questions asking about different pairs of these methods, but none of them reflects my requirements close enough.

Thank you for your considerations with code samples.

Comment: While you can optimize for performance by finding the right data structure, I would have simply moved away from JS. If memory performance turns out to be a big issue then perhaps JS isn't the best language for the job.

Comment: I understand your advice but it is not an option when the app is integrated into a bigger project and needs to keep the language. Probably have to add this to requrements.

Comment: You can still use other languages with nodejs. Either through WASM, or in this case it might be more relevant to use a C++ Addon: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: What data are you storing in the grid?  Your code above implies an object, but is the actual data within this implied object, say integers, whereby unitXarray's (or a few of them) can represent your data?